# VMware Workstation recommends 2 GB of system swap space

Tags: 18.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

When I start a virtual machine, it appears the following message:

[image]

The question is, how to increase the swap file?

I am using VMware® Workstation 15 Pro 15.0.2 build-10952284

This is the actual size of swap:

```
swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G  11M   -2
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if this indicates swap on the client OS, or swap on the host OS.  Can you in your host, execute `swapon` and post the results of that command to your question?

Comment: I updated my post